# ImageMagick : Script giving unexpected result with a different coloured images

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, whiteboard

I am using this script

```
#!/bin/bash
convert "$1" -morphology Convolve DoG:15,100,0 -negate -normalize -blur 0x1 -channel RBG -level 60%,91%,0.1 "$2"
```

On one of the input it gave this result-
[image: input 1]
[image: output 1]

while on the other example it gave-
[image: input 2]
[image: output 2]

What could I change to get clean up the green board image I have like the whiteboard one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to adjust the channel/level correction. Something like `50%,81%,0.1`. Also switch the [-morphology](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#morphology) to `EdgeIn Octagon`. Adjusting the blur & maybe switch colorspace at the end could help.

```sh
#!/bin/bash 
convert "$1" \
        -morphology EdgeIn Octagon \
        -negate -normalize -blur 0x2 \
        -channel RGB -level 50%,81%,0.1 \
        -colorspace Gray \
        "$2"
```

[image: Blackboard Imagemagick]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have few doubts though. Why did you put colorspace as gray ? Can I do this while preserving the original colours (In the original script the colour is preserved) ? Do you have any suggestions for preserving the smoothness of the edges? They seem thicker.

Comment: No need for the colorspace, completely optional. The thickness was increased by adjusting the blur. Checkout the usage documentation on [Morphology](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#difference) for great examples on preserving the edges.